# Storing a string from a text field as a Player name Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to have multiple players for a card matching game. I have made a class that is a child of NSObject called Player. A Player object will have a name, high score, last score, and boolean is currently playing instance. I am trying to create a new player every time a new name is entered into a text field. I will work on storing the players later. Right now I just wish to make a new Player, have a user enter their name in the text field. And store the user's  response in the text field. The following is my Player.m file

```
    #import "Player.h"

    @implementation Player

    -(NSString *) nameOfPlayer:(Player *)playerName{
        return self.name;
    }

    -(void) setPlayerName:(NSString *) nameOf{
        self.name = nameOf;
        self.lastScore = 0;
        self.highestScore = 0;
        self.playing = YES;
        return;
    }

    -(id)init{
        self = [super init];
        self.name = @"";
        self.lastScore = 0;
        self.highestScore = 0;
        self.playing = YES;
        return self;
   }

   @end
```

I didn't originally have that init until I tried looking for a solution online. I am a bit new to iOS coding so I wasn't sure how to set up a constructor (or if they even have those). Below is how I tried to instantiate a Player object:

```
    - (IBAction)handleButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
        Player * friend = nil;
        nameText = self.nameEntryField.text;
        [friend setPlayerName:nameText];
        NSLog(@"%@", [friend nameOfPlayer:friend]);
    }
```

My app breaks its thread as soon as I try to setPlayerName. I am a bit stuck on this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "My app breaks its thread"?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)handleButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
        Player * friend = [[Player alloc] init]; // Initialize this
        nameText = self.nameEntryField.text;
        [friend setPlayerName:nameText];
        NSLog(@"%@", [friend nameOfPlayer:friend]);
 }
```

You have done like `Player * friend = nil;` mean this is the nil object. And then you are trying to use method `setPlayerName:`on nil object. Because of this app breaks.

So you need to initialize object using `[[Player alloc] init]`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! It still breaks at [friend setPlayerName:nameText]; Now however, I know friend is not nil when it gets here. I've also changed setPlayerName to only change the name. I'll try to play around with it, but thanks for helping me with the constructor issues. (I'm used to Java myself)

Comment: @PatrickWilliamWalsh Just for your note. When you are going to create new object you need to Initialize that and whenever you want to hold value from other data holders then simply you can create object and reference it, no need to initialize this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarassing. I was unfamiliar with the xCode IDE and accidentally had selected that line of code for a breakpoint. The code is fine after previous answer.